# Why is critical opalescence localized in this classroom demonstration?

Tags: thermodynamics, scattering, education, critical-phenomena

In Baierlein's *Thermal Physics*, he describes a classroom demonstration:

> A sealed vertical chamber contains a carefully measured amount of carbon dioxide under high pressure. To begin with, the system is in thermal equilibrium at room temperature... A distinct meniscus separates the clear liquid phase from the vapor phase above it.
>
> Now heat the system with a hairdryer. The meniscus rises (because the liquid expands), and gentle boiling commences. Next the meniscus becomes diffuse, and then it disappears....
>
> Now turn off the heater and turn on a fan; blowing room temperature air over the cylinder will cool it–but relatively slowly (in comparison with the earlier heating). For a long time, nothing seems to happen. Then—suddenly!–a wide vertical band of turbulence appears. In reflected light, turbulent region of appears bluish white; in transmitted light, it is rusty brown.

Click on the image below to see a demonstration of this, provided by the Wesleyan Physics Department.  (The apparatus in the video was quite possibly designed and/or built by Baierlein himself, who taught at Wesleyan.)

[image: IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE]

The explanation is that when the temperature of the carbon dioxide approaches the critical point, the correlation length of the density fluctuations is comparable to the wavelengths of light, causing a sudden increase in scattering — first in the blue end of the spectrum (appearing red in transmitted light), and then at all visible wavelengths.

I showed my students this video earlier today, and one of them asked, "Why does the turbulent band appear at the location it does?  Why is it localized, instead of having the whole tube of gas turn turbulent all at once?"  I did not have a good answer to this question at the time, though I speculated that it involved density gradients  between the top and the bottom of the gas sample.

So I put it to this stack: **Why is the turbulence localized when the system falls below the critical temperature, rather than occurring throughout the system?  Why does the correlation length seem to be position-dependent during the transition?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thought is correct. The gravitational field introduces a variation of density in the vertical direction. Therefore, in a vertical container, we have a whole isotherm as a function of the height, and only at some height, the fluid is close enough to the critical density. This is the basis of the clever method devised by Lorentzen to measure the isotherms by measuring the refraction index as a function of the height. It is possible to find details about this and related issues in the old but excellent Heller's review paper in Rep. Prog. in Phys. 30, 731 (1967).